# Solving this integral using Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I've tried without sucess to solve this integral:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}(1+x^2)^{-n}\,\text{d}x.$$

I know that the way to solve it, is by using the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Hint: look at the function $1/(1+x^2)$. The solution is very straightforward.

Comment: Yes. Just show that the integrands converge pointwise to ... and that they are dominated by ...

Comment: When asking questions on this site it is customary to include your thoughts about the problem as well as what you have tried to do to solve it.

Comment: OK, I see that the integrands converge to pi/4 (without the limit) but what about n ?

Comment: First calculate

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x^2)^{-n},
$$

then use the dominated convergence theorem to say that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{-n} \,dx = \int_0^1 \left(\,\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x^2)^{-n}\right) \,dx.
$$
Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: No, the integrands do not converge to $\pi/4$. This is the integral of the integrand$_1$.